# How many servers will be need to install OpenStack and CloudStack cluster?

Tags: openstack, apache-cloudstack

If not use simulator or devstack, but use real production cluster, very necessary need will cost how many hosts(or nodes)?

Comment: It will depend on what services you run, how much (compute, storage, etc) capacity you need, what your requirements for resilience are.  And so on.

Comment: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/5185/what-are-the-minimum-hardware-requirements-of-openstack/

Comment: @StephenC Thank you for your link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudStack: 2 (management-servers and DBs) + 2 (Hypervisors) + 1 Storage(If you do not have a Storage Device, maybe you need a server for NFS or iSCSI)
Total: 5 servers for a minimal environment with load-balance and HA.
OpenStack: It depends on the component you have chosen. Every component can be installed in the right one server. But you need one more server for load-balance and HA.
Total: 2 servers for a minimal environment with load-balance and HA.

When planning a cloud platform, the total resource = ManagementServer*2 + Hypervisor*N + Storage(Server Or Storage Device)
Hypervisor number is the total cpus and memorys of how much vms you planned to run.
Storage is how much volumes you want to allocate for all vms.

Answer (score 0):

For Cloudstack, unlike OpenStack, you can use just one physical machine or server for the installation of both the management server as well as agent (for execution of VMs) and yes, the database and NFS shares can be set up on the same machine too (assuming you need it for testing purpose).
You can follow the quick installation guide of Cloudstack here: http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/projects/cloudstack-installation/en/4.11/qig.html

I have personally installed using the above documentation and can assure you the above works fine with CentOS 7.4 too. For more complex setup and architecture you can find more documentation here: http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org. Just be sure to have some free IPs available ;)